# Can a Book of Shadows be used as regular book?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, equipment

A bit of a noob question about the Warlock's Pact of the Tome:

Can the Book of Shadows be used as a regular book? Does it have blank pages one can write on for miscellaneous notes or drawings, maybe? And if ever you summon it again by doing the 1-hour ritual thing, does it retain said notes/drawings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It's up to your DM, but probably

Your book can be whatever your patron decides it should be. The sidebar on PHB 108 describes a variety of appearances:

> Your Book of Shadows might be a fine, gilt-edged tome with spells of enchantment and illusion, gifted to you by the lordly Archfey. It could be a weighty tome bound in demon hide studded with iron, holding spells of conjuration and a wealth of forbidden lore about the sinister regions of the cosmos, a gift of the Fiend. Or it could be the tattered diary of a lunatic driven mad by contact with the Great Old One, holding scraps of spells that only your own burgeoning insanity allows you to understand and cast.

While this passage describes the appearance of the book, it doesn't actually specify whether you are able to write in it. The extent of the modifications you can make to it is therefore up to your patron (your DM) to decide.

However, if you get the invocation "Book of Ancient Secrets" (PHB 110), it states,

> You can now inscribe magical rituals in your Book of Shadows.

This wording suggests you were able to write other things but not magical rituals, and taking the invocation lets you write those rituals.

As for being able to recover the same book, PHB 108 has this to say:

> If you lose your Book of Shadows, you can perform a 1-hour ceremony to receive a replacement from your patron. This ceremony can be performed during a short or long rest, and it destroys the previous book.

The wording of "replacement" and the fact that it destroys the previous one seems to say that you get a brand new book that has the same properties, not an exact copy of your original book.

Again, your patron/DM has the power/latitude to decide otherwise, so you should talk to them about it.